# Style the TextField children of the material ui autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Material UI autocomplete field (https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#css) I have been able to modify everything my custom Autocomplete component has on its own root but not renderedInput of the variant style that is a filled TextField. Currently the class is as such:

```
.MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot[class*="MuiFilledInput-root"] {
    padding-top: 19px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

I can affect the background color of inputRoot:{} but cannot remove these paddings at all. I only want this component to look this way since they add padding for the label above it.

[Codebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-zfu81?file=/demo.js)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to style the `TextField`. Why can't you just create a styled version of `TextField` like you did for `CustomAutocomplete`?

Comment: I suppose I could do that but, with this excercise I am trying to learn how to drill down to components and it’s children’s styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the default styles in order to override it successfully.  The default styles have a class selector plus an attribute selector. You can match this specificity by nesting the same attribute selector within your `inputRoot` class styles as shown below:

```
const CustomAutocomplete = withStyles({
  inputRoot: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    border: "solid",
    '&[class*="MuiFilledInput-root"]': {
      paddingTop: 0,
      paddingLeft: 0
    }
  }
})(Autocomplete);
```

[image: Edit Override Autocomplete inputRoot styles]